# Static C++ Api coverage tool

Tags: c++, static-analysis, test-coverage

Given a set of public headers, and various test code that makes use of these headers, I need to generate a list of used/unused API calls.

I am working with a platform that can not easily have traditional code coverage at runtime, but my requirements are a bit simpler hopefully.

I only need this to occur statically, and it seems as if this should be an easily accomplished thing (Most IDE's show all available function calls). I haven't found an appropriate tool for this though.

Can anyone recommend one? Or point me to the specific term for what I am looking for?

Thank you

Comment: I recommend searching [softwarerecs.se] before posting there.  Software recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Here are some keywords to search the internet:  "c++ static analysis code coverage"

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks, I didn't know about that site. Is there anything I should do to close this one out then? And I tried searching for those terms- the only semi-valid one I found was facebook's infer, which unfortunately didn't work well for me.

Comment: We are using Parasoft C/C++ Test, Coverity and LDRA for static analysis.  I'm amazed you did find any results.  I'm showing [more tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+static+analysis+code+coverage&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), including CppCheck and Klocwork.

Comment: I found tons of tools, just not ones that seemed to do what I needed in particular. I’ll recheck the ones that you mentioned. My guess is that the name “api coverage” may be called something else by these tools- that’s the thing I was unsure if I have the right term for.